# Wrong max length for char datatype in MySQL

Tags: mysql

When character encoding is  `latin1` (single-byte character set), below `SQL` statement execute without error.

```
create table chartype  (chardata char(255));
```

But When character encoding is  `UTF-8` (3 byte for each character) ,

```
create table chartype  (chardata char(255));
```

this statement should throw error but it is executed without any error.
Max length for char datatype is 255 `bytes`, for `UTF-8` encoding it should allow only below statement

```
create table chartype  (chardata char(85));
```

**85*3=255** `bytes` , so **85** is max length for `UTF-8` character set

Please clarify me.

Comment: The docs only say char length is limited to 255, not it's byte length.

Comment: it's working fine, i tested on w3school , you can try it too, [w3Sql](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all)

Answer (score 1):

When you say `CHAR(255)` you're creating a fixed length field that can accommodate 255 characters. This is distinct from bytes. UTF-8 characters vary in length from 1 to 4 bytes depending on which character you're talking about but the default in MySQL is to accommodate only 3-byte length characters.

To handle the full range of Unicode characters you need to use [`utf8mb4`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) encoding.

Be sure to use `VARCHAR` in preference to `CHAR` as `CHAR` is fixed length and creates a lot of wasted space.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html says in part:

> For a VARCHAR column that stores multibyte characters, the effective maximum number of characters is less. For example, utf8mb3 characters can require up to three bytes per character, so a VARCHAR column that uses the utf8mb3 character set can be declared to be a maximum of 21,844 characters.

The same applies to CHAR or TEXT, or any other data type that supports character sets.